# guardar un decimal con punto en lugar de coma desde c# a sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

Necesito almacenar un valor decimal desde C# a una base de datos SQL pero al momento de enviar el parametro a la consulta siempre me lo arroja con coma, es decir si mando un dato como 0.4 en la consulta sale como 0,4 y por ende no me permite ejecutar la consulta a la base de datos.

Tienen alguna idea de como se puede arreglar este problema?
PD ya utilice el metodo de cultureinfo y los demas.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tira error de datos? lo estas pasando como parametro o como construis la consulta?

Comment: porque no te permite ejecutarlo, estas usando parametros cuando ejecutas la consulta? muestra que codigo utilizas y te da problemas

Comment: Un decimal no se guarda con coma, esa es la presentación regional que te está dando el servidor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes revisar la configuración regional de tu servidor SQL, en caso que no la puedas cambiar y que tu campo en la base de datos no sea decimal prueba modificando el dato desde el mismo script de la base de datos con el siguiente ejemplo:

Insert into tabla 
(campo)
values
( replace(valor,',','.')